# Data Factory: JSON data is interpreted as expression - ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=Unable to parse expression

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I want to copy items from

*CosmosDB database**A**/productCollection*

to

*CosmosDB database**B**/productCollection*

Therefore I decided to use Azure Data Factory.
I actived also "Export as-is to JSON files or Cosmos DB collection".

The read operation works as expected.
Unfortunately, the write operation stops because of an error related to the data:

> ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=Unable to parse expression 'Currency'

```
{
"ProductName": "Sample",
"Price": {
    "@Currency": "GBP",
    "$": "2624.83"
}
```

}

I'm not able to change to input data itself.
The output data has to equal the input data.

Is there possiblity, that *@Currency* will not be interpreted as an expression

In ARM, this part is failling:

> Price.{@Currency}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I was able to resolve accordingly.

I am using a Pipeline with a Source that is a Dataset referencing JSON data.

Clicking the button highlighted below.

[image: Dataset Editor]

I had to change the JSON from

```json
{
  "name": "SourceDataset",
  "properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
      "referenceName": "StorageAccountLink",
      "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "Json",
    "typeProperties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
        "container": "test-data"
      }
    },
    "schema": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "@context": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To ( Escaping the @ with @@ )

```json
{
  "name": "SourceDataset",
  "properties": {
    "linkedServiceName": {
      "referenceName": "StorageAccountLink",
      "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "type": "Json",
    "typeProperties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
        "container": "test-data"
      }
    },
    "schema": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "@@context": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "value": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue but it works for me. I used copy activity to transfer data from account A to account B.

[image]

[image]

Additional, if this operation is just need to be executed once, please consider using [Azure Cosmos DB Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#JSON). It's free for usage. You could export the data from cosmos db A as json file then import it into cosmos db B very simply.Also, it could be executed in the cmd so that it could be made as a scheduled job on the windows system.